# Delete files on external hard drive affect SSD?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, recycle-bin

I've got a SSD as my primary hard drive. I have an external HDD hard drive which I use to 
store downloaded files. At the moment I have to delete 80 GB of that external hard drive. I realized that if I delete it normally, it would probably go to the recycle bin of my SSD.

I am wondering how I can delete the files on my HDD without affecting the SSD or putting any files on it?

Comment: Please tag your questions with the relevant OS.  This kind of behaviour is very different in different OS's.

Answer (score 3):

If you delete files on the external drive it will go the the recycle bin on that drive. It will not get moved to the recycle bin on the SSD.

(The recycle bin icon on your desktop merely shows the contents of *all* recycle bins).

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete it to the recycle bin. On my Win machine, holding the shift key after selecting, and then pressing delete deletes the info without sending it to the recycle bin.

Comment: What exactly does this solve?